# постановка задачи дальше, надо совершить порот списка , изменяя ссылки

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++

Постановка задачи: " Дан линейный двусвязный  список из n целых чисел 0, 1, … , −1 (||<100).
Перевернуть список, то есть изменить ссылки так, чтобы его элементы оказались расположенными в обратном порядке."
Я лишь перевернула список, а надо было ИЗМЕНИТЬ ССЫЛКИ. Как решить данную задачу , осуществив поворот изменяя ссылки в функции ReverseList и выводя на экран с помощью функции PrintList.
ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct ListElement
{
    int info;
    ListElement* next;
    ListElement* pred;
};

// Функция вставляет элемент p в список после элемента last;
// возвращает адрес вставленного элемента
ListElement* InsertElementIntoList(ListElement* last, ListElement* p)
{
    p->next = last->next;
    p->pred = last;
    last->next = p;
    p->next->pred = p;
    return p;
}

//создаёт рандомный(заполненный рандомными значениями) список
void CreateRandomList(ListElement*& head, ListElement*& tail, int n)
{
    head = new ListElement;
    tail = new ListElement;

    head->next = tail;
    tail->pred = head;

    ListElement* last = head;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ListElement* p = new ListElement;
        p->info = rand() % 200 - 100;
        last = InsertElementIntoList(last, p);
    }
    return;
}



// Функция выводит двусвязный список со сторожами head и tail на консоль
void PrintList(ListElement* head, ListElement* tail)
{
    ListElement* p = head->next;
    while (p != tail)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << p->info << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Функция выводит на консоль первернутый двусвзный список
void ReverseList(ListElement* head, ListElement* tail)
{



    ListElement* p = tail->pred;
    while (p != head)
    {
        cout << setw(6) << p->info;
        p = p->pred;
    }
    cout << endl;


}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n = 10;
    ListElement* head = NULL, * tail = NULL;

    CreateRandomList(head, tail,n);
    cout << "длина списка 10" << endl;
    

    cout << "Исходный список:" << endl;
    PrintList(head, tail);


    cout << "Перевернутый двусвязный список:" << endl;
    ReverseList(head, tail);


}
```

Comment: Что получится если в каждом узле вы поменяете местами поля `pred` и `next`?

Answer (score 2):

Как написал Stanislav Volodarskiy, вам всего лишь нужно пройти по списку и в каждом узле поменять поля `pred` и `next`, а не выводить список с конца. Ну и конечно не забыть поменять `head` и `tail`.

```
    ListElement* p = head->next;
    while (p != tail)
    {
       swap(p->next, p->pred);
       p = p->pred;
    }
    swap(head->next, tail->pred);
```

Ну и несколько ошибок:
Ошибка в функции `PrintList()` - она выводит не весь список. Точнее, она не выводит первый и последний элемент.

```
void PrintList(ListElement* head, ListElement* tail)
{
    ListElement* p = head->next; // начало вывода со второго элемента
    while (p != tail) // конец вывода на предпоследнем элементе
    {
        cout << setw(5) << p->info << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

И видимо чтобы "подогнать" под правильный ответ функция `CreateRandomList()` делает список на 2 элемента больше.

```
CreateRandomList(ListElement*& head, ListElement*& tail, int n)
{
    head = new ListElement; // создано 2 элемента
    tail = new ListElement;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // создано ещё n элементов
    {
        ListElement* p = new ListElement;
    }
}
```

И почему-то выделяя память под элементы списка, вы не озаботились освободить её.